# Determine the parameters for any Hamming code over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

> Determine the parameters for any Hamming code over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

I am new to Coding Theory. I’m confused what "the parameters" exactly mean.
What specifically am I supposed to determine?

Comment: Hi,there.My full question is what I ask above and the question is assigned by by teacher and I don’t know why you think it is unclear for asking.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are the length of the code , minimum distance and dimension

> Definition  . (Linear codes) $A$ code $C$ is a linear code if it is a subspace of the vector space $F_q^{n}$  of dimension $n$ over the field $GF(q)$.
>
> If $C$ has dimension $k$ over $GF(q)$,
>   we say that C is an $[n; k]$-code, and
>
> If $C$ has the minimum distance $d$ we say $C$ is an $[n; k; d]$-code